# Issues with Jquery onload and RequireJS in a legacy system

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have a legacy spagetti system that I'm trying to start using RequireJs with. Once issue I keep having is that there are several jquery.ready() statements in various places in included files.

These included files are used both on the page that I am trying to use RequireJS with and also on lots of other pages that aren't going to be using requireJS for my next copy live.

The issue is that for the page that uses requireJs JQuery hasn't loaded yet when the included file is executed.

I know that this should go inside the main RequireJs file where dependencies will have been loaded, but at the moment I'm being forced to duplicate this onload code there and in the original place (using and if statement to check what page it's on to see if I should skip the onload because it's dealt with in the Require js file).

Is there a better way to do this? I wonder would I be better including jquery with traditional mean rather than trying to do this right now. Would the [combined RequireJS jquery file](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#samplejquery)  solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a very similar situation. My API needs to work wherever my users happen to place it in the document load order, no matter how many different version of jquery they manage to load into their page.

My code was using the combined RequireJS jquery file, but I have recently moved it to comply with the [new guidelines on using jquery and requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap)

The new technique allows you to confine *your* version of jquery in your local scope, free from other interference or plugins.

I found that, and a little usage of [jQuery.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) Allowed my code to survive in all kinds of spaghetti :-)

_Pez